# Creating a global Vim configuration, including separate configuration files for plugins?

Tags: arch-linux, vim, vimrc

I use Arch Linux (ARM, but irrelevant) on a server machine, and I want to create a global configuration for Vim, based on my current personal configuration.

I have already moved my ~/.vimrc to /etc/vimrc, and that works fine, but I want to configure the filetype plugin globally too. My personal configuration files for this are in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/. A separate file is needed for each filetype.

I've tried copying this .vim folder into /etc (but naming it 'vim' rather than '.vim'), but to no effect. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The system-wide Vim runtime files are not located under `/etc`. Inside Vim, type `:set runtimepath?`, and it will tell you all directories, usually including something like `/usr/share/vim/vim73`.

You can either put your config in there (but be aware that these existing locations might get overwritten by package updates!), or, if you have a customized global `/etc/vimrc`, anyway, you can also add any arbitrary directory via `:set runtimepath+=/etc/myvimstuff` there.

Try to avoid the `after` directory; this is meant for *user* customization.